# Do covariance and contravariance work with generic type parameters?

Tags: c#-4.0, delegates, covariance

I am trying to use a delegate, Func <object, T>, covariantly without success. Despite T being convertible to object, Func<object, T> does not seem to be convertible to Func<object, object> even though Func<object, string> (or any other concrete type) can be converted to Func<object, object> as would be expected. See code demonstrating the problem below.

```
public void Register<T>(Expression<Func<object[], T>> factory, Func<bool> constructorSelectionPredicate) 
    {   object o1;
        T o2 = default(T);
        o1 = o2; // works fine

        Func<object, object> f1 = o => o.GetType();
        Func<object, T> f2 = o => o as T;

        f1 = f2; //gives conversion error.
        f1 = f2 as Func<object, object>; // f2 as Func<object, object> is always null

        Func<object[], string> f1 = input => input.GetType().Name;
        Func<object[], object> f2 = input => new object();

        f2 = f1 // works fine

    }
```

The [msdn documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd799517.aspx#DelegateVariantTypeParameters) does not address the generic type parameter case directly from what I have seen. Can anyone explain what's going on here?

Answer (score 0):

You need to apply a type constraint on your generic argument.

Change the your function prototype to:

```
public void Register<T>(Expression<Func<object[], T>> factory, Func<bool> constructorSelectionPredicate) where T : class
```

In this line:

```
Func<object[], object> f2 = input => new object();
```

... you will also need to cast the object you are creating to T.

Comment: Are you sure? I tried the class constraint to no avail previously. I also tried to use `where T: object` as well, but the compiler does not allow that. I'll double check though just to make sure that I didn't  make some other silly error through sleep deprivation!

Comment: It compiled for me when I made the two changes mentioned above... what is the error the compiler is giving you now?

Comment: Or is it some strange runtime behavior you're seeing?